# How do you tap the key of this object?

Tags: javascript, json, api, object, javascript-objects

I'm working on a project for myself (gotta keep busy). I have JavaScript that taps API, and retrieves data as follows:

```
 {
  '2020-12-18:95': {
    '45.0': [ [Object] ],
    '50.0': [ [Object] ],
    '55.0': [ [Object] ],
    '60.0': [ [Object] ]
  }
}
```

How do I enumerate through that? When I

> object.2020-12-18:95

to get to the strike prices, I get error mesg. Your help is appreciated

Comment: `object["2020-12-18:95"]`

Comment: From there you can use `for..in` to iterate through the object keys

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate through as:

```js
const data = {
  '2020-12-18:95': {
    '45.0': [ {} ],
    '50.0': [ {} ],
    '55.0': [ {} ],
    '60.0': [ {} ]
  }
}


const result = data['2020-12-18:95']

Object.keys(result)
      .map(key => console.log(key, result[key]))
```

From the documentations:

> The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property names, iterated in the same order that a normal loop would.

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.